# Film in which a boy befriends an old talking boot

Tags: story-identification

I watched this (color, not very "ancient") film about 1979 on TV. It was made in some country from the former Soviet bloc. I don't know if it was made for cinema or for TV.

The boy finds the boot when he goes fishing. At first, he plans to throw it in the river, but the boot asks him not to. They become friends, but eventually the boy goes playing ice hockey and has to change his shoes. He puts the old boot on the roof of a car to keep his hands free and loses it.

Comment: BTW, there should be a "list of talking objects" entry at wikipedia.

Comment: Well, you have my interest...

Comment: Searched same movie, found more info: "Then his parents punished for something and locked him in the bathroom, he turned on the water and out of the hole came little people on the boat, they were cartoon-like and the boy became small also and swam with them" https://cccp-film.ru/video/rubrics/skazki.html